# How to get latest comment effectively using graph API even though comment to old post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I need to fetch the Facebook comments even though some comments are for old posts (may be a few weeks back) , but downloading the full list via Graph API and syncing it on every page view is extremely inefficient.

Does anyone knows the efficient way about how to extract the latest comments? says all comments from yesterday. Since FQL is going to be obsolete in API 2.1 so how can I do it using Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to fetch the latest comments relatively often (in my case every hour) you can consider saving the last "next page cursor" for each post and try restarting from there.

From [the Graph API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#reading) -

> Cursor-based pagination is the most efficient method of paging and should always be used where possible - a cursor refers to a random string of characters which mark a specific item in a list of data. Unless this item is deleted, the cursor will always point to the same part of the list, but it will be invalidated if an item is removed. Therefore, your app shouldn't store any older cursors or assume that they will still be valid.
>
> Cursors can't be stored for long periods of time and expected to still work. They are meant to paginate through the result set in a short period of time.

Facebook expects you not to save cursors for future use, but I guess there's no harm in trying anyway and then degrade on fetching all comments (or just the first N pages) if the cursor fails.

EDIT - from my tests cursors are still valid after 12 hours. Maybe it's not a time limit expiration, it could be that a cursor is invalidated if the last comment of that page gets deleted or something.